# How to preview items which are created programmatically in .xib file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode7.3

I want to preview some items which are created programmatically to see how they are looking on view. It is hard to make changes in .m file after rebuild application to see differences. Is there any way to see preview it? Thanks.

Comment: [Creating a Custom View That Renders in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/Chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html)

Comment: i just try to implement `IB_DESIGNABLE ` for corner radius. I think this will help you. https://github.com/JayeshThanki/IBInspectableCornerRadius

Answer (score 2):

You have to use IB_DESIGNABLE macros.

Please, read step-by-step docs [Creating a Custom View That Renders in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/Chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html)